# Background Image Not saving to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'am trying to save background image to local storage. Image changing works perfectly but its not saving to Local storage please check my code.

```
$(".theme3").click(function () {
var backgroundImage = 'my image Url';
localStorage.removeItem('background-image');
$('.Menutopcover').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');
localStorage.setItem("background-image", backgroundImage);
}
```

Comment: Define "Not saving". What is the issue? `setItem` should work as expected in that context as long as `backgroundImage` is a string.

Comment: Working well your code, https://jsfiddle.net/d53cyqs7/2/

Comment: saving means "not showing" from local storage

Comment: since your code never **reads** localStorage, how do you know?

Comment: `"not showing" from local storage` ... localStorage stores text ... in this case, it'd be something like `http:/example.com/someimage.jpg` ... that's just a bunch of letters, so ... how can that "show" an image?

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle for this

Comment: @kannanD.S **where** are you acquiring the value? there is nothing wrong in the above code, `setItem` would throw an exception as well if something goes wrong.

Comment: I got solution friends. Thanks for supporting

Comment: if (localStorage.getItem("background_image") != null) {
                    getImage = localStorage.background_image;
                    $('.Menutopcover').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImage + ')');
                }